# Random Imgur Image upon page refreshing

Tags: imgur

I want to make a page where everytime the page refreshes a random image form imgur loads up.

The way this can be done is by the last few digits in the URL
http://imgur.com/gallery/**sl8xtF0**

I wondering how to change that everytime the page loads.

Thank you and sorry if this is worded a bit strange.